IF statement nested with 3 ANDs and 3 TIMEVALUEs

=IF(
    AND(
        I2="Y", 
        O2="Y", 
        G2<=TIMEVALUE("14:00")
    ), 
    "Y", 
    IF(
        AND(
            I2="Y", 
            O2="N", 
            G2<=TIMEVALUE("12:00")
        ), 
        "Y", 
        IF(
            AND(
                I2="N", 
                H2<=TIMEVALUE("6:00")
            ), 
            "Y", 
            "N"
        )
    )
)

EDIT:
Here is the formula: =IF(AND(I2="Y",O2="Y",F2<=TIMEVALUE("14:00")),"Y",IF(AND(I2="Y",O2="N",F2<=TIMEVALUE("12:00")),"Y",IF(AND(I2="N",H2<=6),"Y","N")))
I am trying to automate this audit form for a process at work (see attached image). I want the Q column (ON TIME?) to populate Y or N based on the following conditions:

If patient admit was overnight (Column I = Y), AND on a weekend (Column O = Y), AND med rec finish (Tech) before 2pm (Column F <= 14:00)
OR
If patient admit was overnight (Column I = Y), AND not on a weekend (Column O = N), AND med rec finish (Tech) before noon (Column F <= 12:00)
OR
If patient admit not overnight (Column I = N), on any day, AND med rec finish (Tech) within 6 hours from admit time (Column H <= 6)
THEN
The med rec was completed on time (Column Q = Y) // if conditions are not met, then med rec was not completed on time (Column Q = N)

I thought I had it correct but the first test line is showing "N" but I was expecting it to show "Y". Hopefully someone can point out where my formula went wrong.
EDIT 2:
Thank you everyone, your suggestions worked and a learned a new tool! With the help from the evaluate formula option, I found out since my dates were in the same cells as the time, my formula was failing on the F2<=TIMEVALUE("14:00") piece.

Why are you nesting IF statements, rather than using OR (or IFS)?

I would advise you to go to the "Formulas" tab in the ribbon, and then using the "Evaluate Formula" button to step through and see where it goes wrong.  Since your formula looks to do what you want, I strongly suspect that the issue is your data: i.e. you might have a Space after the "Y" or "N".  And while "Y"="Y" and "N"="N", you will find that "Y "<>"Y" and "N "<>"N".  (That can be fixed with the TRIM function, e.g. TRIM(I2)="Y", since TRIM("Y ")="Y" — but, only if the whitespace is a space.  It doesn't work for New Lines)

@Chronocidal, I'd delete my answer if you post one.

Hi, your formula worked as expected when I created a sheet using your image. Please let me know if you've already solved it yourself using suggestions from the comments - I'll delete my answer.

Thank you I figured it out with the evaluate formula! Will definitely be saving that and the TRIM function for later use.

Here's dynamic array formula you could try (in a separate column first):

with IFS and TRIM (as Chronocidal also suggested)
if the results don't match what's expected, replace the ontime with other variables and see
adjust the last_row calculation to match your data
assuming you have Excel 2021 or later

enter in the first cell of On Time? (Q2):
=LET(last_row, XMATCH(TRUE, ISNUMBER(A:A), , -1),
    overnight, TRIM(I2:INDEX(I:I, last_row)) = "Y",
    weekend, TRIM(O2:INDEX(O:O, last_row)) = "Y",
    finished_before2pm, G2:INDEX(G:G, last_row) <= TIMEVALUE("14:00"),
    finished_before_noon, G2:INDEX(G:G, last_row) <= TIMEVALUE("12:00"),
    completed_lt_6hrs, H2:INDEX(H:H, last_row) <= TIMEVALUE("6:00"),
    on_time, IFS(
        overnight * weekend * finished_before2pm, "Y",
        overnight * NOT(weekend) * finished_before_noon, "Y",
        NOT(overnight) * completed_lt_6hrs, "Y",
        TRUE,"N"),
    on_time
)


